# how to make web service calls in a for loop in play framework with scala

Tags: web-services, rest, asynchronous, playframework

I'm new to play framework. I want to use it to make REST API calls to a web services to get information for all users in the system. There are 2 steps:
1. get the ids of all users
2. get the information of each user

with the for-comprehesion, I can write the 2 request in this way:

```
for {
  uids <- getUids()
  users <- getUsers(uids)
} yield Ok(s"${users.size} users(s), ${users}")
```

getUids() is straightforward, but in getUsers(), I cannot send all user ids in the REST API once. I can send at most 100 user ids at one time, which means I need a for loop to make successive calls in   batches of size 100. But all these WS requests are async, how can I know when all the requests are done that I can combined the response to the final result and return.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would compile, but try something like this:

```
for {
  uids <- getUids()
  users <- users <- Future.sequence(uids.grouped(100).toList.map(listOf100Ids => getUsers(listOf100Ids))).map(_.flatten)
} yield Ok(s"${users.size} users(s), ${users}")
```

Step1 - Split your userids into chunks of 100:

```
uids.grouped(100).toList // Get something like List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6))
```

Step2 - Use the user ids to fetch the actual users:

```
.toList.map(listOf100Ids => getUsers(listOf100Ids)) // Result is now something like List(List(Future[User]), List(Future[User]))
```

Step3 - Go from List[List[Future[User]]] to Future[List[List[User]]]

```
Future.sequence(listOfFutureUsers)
```

Step4 - Go from Future[List[List[User]]] to Future[List[User]]

```
futureListOfListOfUsers.map(_.flatten)
```

Comment: `Future.sequence` does not execute the `Future`s in sequential order. Grouping them here effectively does nothing, and they will still all fire off immediately.